# FileInput as line versus fileinput as string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a list of files that I want to iterate over with RegEx replacements, some on individual lines, some that require multiline matches.

I am able to iterate over lines in a list of files and write to disk using this method.

```
import fileinput, re

ListFiles = ['in/spam.txt', 'in/eggs.txt', 'in/spam2.txt', 'in/eggs2.txt', 
'in/spam3.txt', 'in/eggs3.txt', 'in/spam4.txt', 'in/eggs4.txt',
'in/spam5.txt', 'in/eggs5.txt']

with fileinput.input(files=(ListFiles), inplace=True, backup='.bak') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub(r'this','that', line)
        print(line, end='')
```

Now I want to gather the output lines in `f` as a string, for which I can run multiline RegEx routines.

I tried a `with(open)`, which I have been able to use to use with ReGex a single file, but it does not take a list as an argument, only a file name.

```
with open("spam.txt", "w") as f: # sample other use, list not allowed here.
    data = f.read()
    data = re.sub(r'sample', r'sample2', data)
    print(data, file=f)
```

And I tried to gather `f` as a string into new variable data, as follows:

```
data = f(str)
data = re.sub(r'\\sc\{(.*?)\}', r'<hi rend="small_caps">\1</hi>', data) ## Ignore that this not multiline Regex for sample purposes only.
print(data)
```

But that produces error, that FileInput is not callable.

Is there a way that I can iterate and apply RegEx to files as line and as the same files as string in same with statement?

Comment: Note that if you just want to replace `text1` to `text2` like `line = re.sub(r'this','that', line)`, you can simply use `line = line.replace('this', 'that')` instead.

Comment: Are you trying to do multiline matching across files, or only within each file?  If the latter, why not just iterate through the files and read each individually?  `fileinput` is just a convenience class that streamlines opening and reading a bunch of files.  It uses the regular `open` and `readline` functions.

Comment: I am using more complicated RegEx, so line.replace is not robust enough. I excluded them for clarity in question. J. F. Sebastian has answered with a great solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is ok to read individual files into memory as a whole then to perform multiline replacements in a list of files, you could process one file at a time:

```
for filename in ListFiles:
    with open(filename) as file: 
        text = file.read() # read file into memory
    text = text.replace('sample\n1', 'sample2') # make replacements
    with open(filename, 'w') as file: 
        file.write(text) # rewrite the file
```

Comment: Thanks very much J. F. Sebastian. As a subsidiary command to `with file.input`, on same level as `for line in f:`, you've solved a problem that has been bedeviling me for days.  Now onto writing my 70 or so RegEx's.